# Reading content from file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, rtf

```
NSString *contentPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test2" ofType:@"rtf"];
NSData *databuffer;

NSFileHandle *file = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:contentPath];

if (file == nil)
    NSLog(@"Failed to open file");

databuffer = [file readDataToEndOfFile];

[file closeFile];

NSString *contentText =[[NSString alloc] initWithData:databuffer encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

debugLog(@"%@",contentText);

[textView setText:contentText];
[contentText release];

//[textView setText:[bookObj commentary]];
[self.view addSubview:textView];
```

Output:

> **i\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1038\cocoasubrtf320
>
>   {\fonttbl\f0\froman\fcharset0 Times-Roman;}
>
>   {\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
>
>   \margl1440\margr1440\vieww9000\viewh8400\viewkind0
>
>   \deftab720
>
>   \pard\pardeftab720\ql\qnatural**
>
> **\f0\fs24 \cf0** A stream is a fundamental abstraction in programming: a sequence of bits transmitted serially from one point to another point. Cocoa provides three classes to represent streams and facilitate their use in your programs: NSStream, NSInputStream, and NSOutputStream. With the instances of these classes you can read data from, and write data to, files and application memory. You can also use these objects in socket-based

How to filter those bold data..???

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to load RTF text into a plain string. Use NSAttributedString instead or convert your file to plain text.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you were planning to edit this text as well or just display it but the only workable way I know is to use a `UIWebView`

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test2" ofType:@"rtf"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webview loadRequest:request];
```